# Como exibir imagens dinamicamente no angular com a diretiva ngFor

Tags: angular, imagem

Bom, eu estou tentando criar um slider de fotos, no qual preciso deixar dinamico para não ter que copiar e colar infinitamente alguns trechos.

Tenho um array com os nomes das imagens:

```
array: any = [{id: 1, nome: 'imagem1'}, {id: 2, nome: 'imagem2'} ];
```

Estou exibindo-as no html com laço for do angular (7)

```
<span *ngFor="let item of array ">
  <img class="slides" [src]="root + item.nome + '.jpg'">
</span>
```

Ao tentar pegar a tag img `const slide: any = document.getElementsByClassName('slides');` (que retorna um HTMLCollection) tenho sempre um length 0, acho que porque o angular não consegue esperar o ngFor (não tenho certeza)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No caso preciso dessa collection para fazer com que as imagens apareçam de acordo com meu array.

Alguém teria uma noção ou alguma alternativa (mesmo que completamente diferente no código)?

Comment: Tá muito estranho isso aí, pq independente se as imagens estão com o caminho correto ou não (o que causaria um erro no console de 404 - not found), o **ngFor** está percorrendo um array com tamanho 2, então obrigatoriamente, teria que ser criado duas tags `img` no Html. Deve ter alguma coisa a mais aí que não postou!

Comment: @LeAndrade, o caminho está correto (seria essa minha variavel 'root' acima), pois se faço sem o ngFor funciona, mas ai teria que ficar copiando e colando para uma nova imagem. O exemplo que peguei foi o do W3 (https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/tryit.asp?filename=tryw3css_slideshow_self) que nesse caso, ele percorre o array já que ele tem uma coleção no template (3 tags img) e eu só tenho uma.

Assim ele referencia como ' x[slideIndex-1]', mas não tenho itens nesse array, ACHO pq no meu template tenho apenas uma tag img e o ngFor não termina de "executar" pra entregar os 3 img para o .ts

Comment: Não sei o que está acontecendo aí no seu código, testei ele aqui e funcionou normal, renderizou as imagens no html e dei um **console.log(slides)** no ngOnInit() e retornou o HTMLCollection com tamanho 2 normalmente.

Comment: Então @LeAndrade encontrei o problema. Foram dois: Um porque estava setando o valor do array no onInit e por sua vez estava setando em momento diferente do template (obvio) resolvi setando o valor antes. E o segundo era na hora de setar o style.display, como no exemplo do W3. Como eu precisava dos valores que eu pegava dentro de uma funcao, rodei essa funcao dentro do AfterViewInit, para assim pegar quando realmente tivesse o valor dos imgs completo...
Muito obrigado pela força, consegui depois de debugar o inicio como voce disse que conseguiu... Valeu!